# Font Change restarts application in android

Tags: java, android

When I change the system font on an android device, my app is getting restarted (not just current activity). I am sure of this as the pid itself is different.

Is there any way to prevent application restart?

This question is related to:
[Handle runtime activity configuration when font change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894126/handle-runtime-activity-configuration-when-font-change)

As described there, there is no configChanges attribute which can be used to handle system font change (fontScale works only for font size change).

Comment: There is no facility in Android for the user to change the system font face. Whatever you are doing goes beyond the bounds of Android itself, either from some device manufacturer extension, or from some rooted app.

Comment: I am testing this on a Samsung device. Maybe this feature is added on.

Answer (score 3):

You should add the below line in your `manifest`. But you have to handle the configuration change by yourself.`android:configChanges="fontScale"`

[Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: Unfortunately `fontScale` works only for size of the font and not for the font itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the same as when you change the orientation of your phone. The activity restarts. You can store information as needed by overriding `protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and `protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

More info and examples can be found in this guide: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html